# Why I dont see the "Page-Layout columns" category at my columns list in the site settings?

Tags: page-layout

I have 2 environments. I see at one environment the category "Page-Layout columns". Inside this column I see the column "ArticleByLine". I am figuring out if this is a column out of the box or a manual created column.

Do I need to activate some feature to get the category "Page-Layout columns" with inside of it the columns?

Answer (score 0):

solution is to activate the publishing feature..